# Optimized way to count the number of lines with conditions

Tags: python

I have seen that a fast way to count the number of lines in a file is to do like this way:

```
n_lines=sum(1 for line in open(myfile))
```

I would like to know if it is possible to put some conditions in the sum function in order to have something like that:

```
n_lines=sum(1 for line in open(PATHDIFF) if line=='\n' break if line.startswith('#') continue)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, with certain restrictions. You are passing a generator expression as the argument to `sum`, and a generator expression can take one expression with the `if` clause. You can combine your conditions like this:

```
n_lines=sum(1 for line in open(PATHDIFF)
                if line != '\n' and not line.startswith('#'))
```

However, this doesn't short-circuit the iteration of your file when you hit a `newline`; it continues to read through the file to the end. To avoid that, you can use `itertools.takewhile`, which will only read from the iterator produced by the generator expression until you read a newline.

```
from itertools import takewhile
n_lines = sum(1 for line in takewhile(lambda x: x != '\n',
                                      open(PATHDIFF))
                   if not line.startswith('#'))
```

You can also use `itertools.ifilterfalse` to fill the same role as the condition clause of the generator expression.

```
from itertools import takewhile, ifilterfalse
n_lines = sum(1 for line in ifilterfalse(lambda x: x.startswith('#'),
                                         takewhile(lambda x: x != '\n',
                                                   open(PATHDIFF))))
```

Of course, now your code starts to look like you are writing in Scheme or Lisp. The generator expression is a little easier to read, but the `itertool` module is useful for building up modified iterators that you can
pass around as distinct objects.

---

On a different topic, you should always make sure you close any files you open, which means not using anonymous file handles in your iterators. The cleanest way to do this is to use a `with` statement:

```
with open(PATHDIFF) as f:
    n_lines = sum(1 for line in f if line != '\n' and not line.startswith('#'))
```

The other examples can be similarly modified; just replace `open(PATHDIFF)` with `f` where it occurs.

Comment: You should add "with open(XXX) as f" to your examples, otherwise the file will stay opened after the operation, util the script exits or the garbage collector runs.

Answer (score 2):

In fact there's a fast way (*borrowing from [Funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy/blob/c683cbf97b23fc247c87dd9ac0f861010973801e/funcy/seqs.py)*) to compute the length of an iterator without consuming it:

**Example:**

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import count, izip


def ilen(seq):
    counter = count()
    deque(izip(seq, counter), maxlen=0)  # (consume at C speed)
    return next(counter)


def lines(filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return ilen(
            None for line in f
            if line != "\n" and not line.startswith("#")
        )


nlines = lines("file.txt")
```

Comment: I don't have time to `timeit` now but I'll have to give it a closer look.

Comment: Neither do i! (*have time to ``timeit`` all the various solutions*); but I suspect it *might* be a bit faster since a lot of what it's using is written in C/CPython.

Comment: I timed it. This implementation of `ilen()` is faster than `sum(1 for ...)`.

Comment: @Suor Ahh fantastic! We should all upvote this in that case as the most optimal solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `break` nor `continue` in a list comprehension or generator expression so the "correct" syntax for your example would be:

```
nlines = 0
with  open(PATHDIFF) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line=='\n':
            # not sure that's _really_ what you want
            # => this will exit the loop at the first 'empty' line
            break 
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        nlines += 1
```

Now if you really want to exit at the first 'empty' line AND want to make it a single-liner, you can also use `itertools.takewhile()`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
with open(XXX) as f: 
    nlines = sum(1 for line in takewhile(lambda l: l != '\n', f) 
                 if not line.starstwith("#"))
```

Comment: You should add "with open(XXX) as f" to your first example, too. Otherwise, the file will stay opened for a long time (until the script finishes or the garbage collector kicks in).

Comment: @vog Obviously yes (copy-pasted from the OP's snippet and not corrected). Note that in CPython the file should be garbage-collected at the end of the `for` block (CPython uses mainly a reference-count based GC and obviously the anonymous file object will have it's ref count at zero at this point), but yes, relying on unspecified implementation details is totally unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import ifilter,takewhile
with open("test.txt") as f:
     fil = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(str.strip, ifilter(lambda line: not line.startswith("#"), f)))
     print(fil)
```

Or maybe indexing would be faster than the `startswith` calls:

```
 fil = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(str.strip, ifilter(lambda x: x[0] != "#", f)))
```

Using `str.strip` will catch any empty lines.

Indexing does seem to be a bit faster:

```
In [11]: from itertools import ifilter,takewhile

In [12]: %%timeit
   ....: with open("test.txt") as f:
   ....:      fil = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(str.strip, ifilter(lambda x: x[0] != "#", f)))
   ....: 

1000 loops, best of 3: 400 µs per loop

In [13]: %%timeit
   ....: with open("test.txt") as f:
   ....:      fil = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(str.strip, ifilter(lambda line: not line.startswith("#"), f)))
   ....: 

1000 loops, best of 3: 531 µs per loop
```

Comment: @JamesMills, I was beginning to think you were having a liquid lunch ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed and don't mind using bash

```
grep -v '^#' yourfile | wc -l
```

Will count all lines that do not start with # and it will be way faster than python.

Comment: This is a bash solution; not Python as the OP's tag suggests.

Comment: @JamesMills, OP did not ask for a python solution, the word python is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I beg to differ; it is both implied in the question's content and it's tags

Comment: I think the opposite is implied by the title of the question. So it is rather subjective

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting number of comment lines or non-comment?
If it is something like that then this should work.

```
comment_lines = sum([1 for line in open(PATHDIFF) if line.startswith('#')])
non_comment_lines = sum([1 for line in open(PATHDIFF) if not line.startswith('#')])
```