# Python assistance skipping rows in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write python code that counts the amount of rows in a csv file, but ignores rows containing the text (zzz for example). I have been able to successfully count the rows but I do not know how to write the code so it ignores rows that contain zzz when counting. Any help in this, or at the least pointing me to something to read would be great.

```
import csv

filename = (r"name")

with open(filename, 'r') as csvf:

    csv_csvf = cvs.reader(csvf)
    reader = csv.reader(csvf)
    lines = len(list(reader))

print(lines)
```

Comment: Use list comprehension: `sum(1 for x in lines if "zzz" not in x)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimized way to count the number of lines with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484287/optimized-way-to-count-the-number-of-lines-with-conditions)

Comment: thank you for pointing me in these directions, I ended up going the pandas route for speed. f = pd.read_csv(filename, memory_map=True, skiprows=1, header=None, index_col=False).iloc[:,0]      f1 = f[~f.str.contains("zzz", na=False))